# How does sqlite ON CONFLICT clause work in a column definition?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following example:

```
sqlite> create table FILES (FILENAME VARCHAR(1024) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

With this, I gather from the documentation that an insert that violates this primary key would be ignored.

But that's not happening, the 2. insert gives an error.

```
sqlite> insert into files values ('fileA');
sqlite> insert into files values ('fileA');
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: FILES.FILENAME
```

So, how does ON CONFLICT IGNORE work in the above table, what is its purpose ?

(Note - I know I can also run `insert or ignore into files values ('fileA');`, and that will be ignored, but the question is about the column definition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conflict resolution clause applies to the NOT NULL constraint, so it would ignore only NULL values.

To ignore duplicates, add ON CONFLICT IGNORE directly after the PRIMARY KEY constraint.